# How to use an USB pen drive to install Windows XP when WinToFlash doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to put Windows XP SP2 on my pendrive because I need to format an UMPC via USB port.
I'm trying using USB_multiboot_10, but it fails when I press "P" to format the usb drive (a Kingston Datatraveler G3 - 8GB). I tried formatting with the normal tool of inside Windows 7, but USB_multiboot_10 doesn't recognize the pendrive anyway.

Now, my question is: there is a way or a tool to format an USB drive more accurately than the windows built-in tool?
Or maybe better: there is a way to use an USB drive to install Windows XP (instead of a CD) other than USB_multiboot_10 and WinToFlash? I tried win to flash, it puts data on the USB stick, but when I start the UMPC from USB it says that the file hal.dll is missing..

Comment: `WinToFlash` should be working are you sure your following the instructions? Have you tried using `Windows XP Service Pack 3` instead by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound: No unfortunately I only tried with a copy of Windows XP SP2. Is it so important to compromise the installation?

Comment: Have you tried using a different pen drive? I can confirm from experience that WinToFlash does work with XP.

Comment: @Karan: I have just two pen drives. Both Kingston Datatraveler G3, one of 8GB and one of 32GB..

Comment: Did you try both? See if you can delete all partitions from the drives and then use WinToFlash. If it complains about an unformatted disk, create a single FAT32 partition and try again. You can also try [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) or [WinSetupFromUSB](http://myeeeguides.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/winsetupfromusb-install-windows-xp-from-usb-flash-drive/).

Comment: @Overflowh - `Compromise the installation`...What do you mean by that statement

Comment: @Ramhound: I mean that "not having SP3 will make the installation doesn't work"..

Comment: @Karan: No I tried only the 8GB because the problem with USB_multiboot_10 is that it has problems formatting great drives (greater than 4GB). I tried to delete all partitions, now my drive has an only one partition formatted with FAT32 (I also tried NTFS) and default allocation size. As I said, when I tried WinToFlash it seems to work, put the OS on the drive, but when I try to install in on the UMPC it says that HAL.DLL is missing..

Comment: So did you try the other two programs I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use diskpart by open cmd:

```
diskpart
list disk (you should see your usb drive here)
select disk x (your usb drive)
clean
create partiton primary
active
format fs=ntfs quick
assign
```

After this just copy all files from install medium to the flash drive.
When setting up the device don't plug your flash drive into usb 3.0 ports.